# Connect-Flash and Express give me multiple messages but not type

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express, pug, flash-message

I'm trying to ask a type to a multiple flash message in Connect-Flash - Express and gives me multiple string messages but not "type"

In Route:

```
  app.get '/multiple-flash', (req, res) ->
    req.flash "info", ["Welcome", "Benvenuto"]
    res.redirect '/'
```

In client:

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    title= 'Login'

  body
    p layout

      if message 
        p= message

    -console.log(message)
```

GET /multiple-flash at localhost, but the output in the console does not show "type".

```
GET /multiple-flash 302 1ms - 90
[ [ 'Welcome', 'Benvenuto', ] ]
```

How can I fix? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will be helpful to those who have had the same problem.
In route '/' will be:

```
  app.get '/', (req, res) -> 
    res.render '', 
      message: req.flash()
```

instead previously was wrong with:

```
message: req.flash ('info')
```

that returns only the flash of info.